# MacOS X iSCSI Initiator MPIO or LACP Support

Tags: mac-osx, raid, mac-osx-server, iscsi, xserve

I am trying to find a MacOS X iSCSI Initiator with MPIO or LACP Support to use on MacOS X Server 10.5. We've been looking at ATTO's, but it doesn't MPIO nor LACP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked at [globalSAN](http://www.studionetworksolutions.com/products/product_detail.php?pi=11)?

Does the ATTO one not work or just not officially support MPIO/LACP? The reason I ask is that I *think* MPIO is a L2/L3 thing with iSCSI initiation being higher up the stack - therefore the initiator shouldn't care about the actual LAN setup beneath it - could easily be wrong on that though :)

Comment: ATTO doesn't officially support or recommend MPIO or LACP with their initiator. LACP is between the host and the switch; however, ATTO states reliability issues with it. As for MPIO they make it seem like there is no support for it :( I will look more into globalSAN

Comment: I checked the globalSAN iSCSI initiator and I don't see any support in the software, nor any mention of MPIO in the manuals. Oh well, I guess I have wait until MacOS X 10.7 I guess.